# Extra edges in Delaunay Triangles

Tags: triangulation, delaunay

Please see the attached pictures below. There are few extra edges, and they seem to satisfy "point not inside the circumcircle" property at the time of adding each point. I have already removed the Super Triangle from both the screenshots.

Do I need to rerun the loop to eliminate Bad Triangles? But that's not what the Bowyer-Watson algorithm says. Could someone please help to understand what could be wrong here?

**Edit:** These are the vertices in the processing order for the **1st screenshot**.
(1500, 1500)
(3300, 1500)
(2800, 2800)
(1750, 2600)
(2350, 2900)

**Update 1:**
While repopulating the polygon, I am connecting new point with all the edges. That's why the additional edge is coming up, but I have no idea yet, how to select and ignore individual point of edge.

(Sorry, I can't post my code here. Any suggestions would be really helpful.)

[image: Annotated Coordinates]

[image: Erroneous Delaunay Triangulation]

[image: Another example]

Comment: This is hard to pin down without knowing what your implementation of that algorithm is actually doing. Maybe you could at least mention in what order the points in the two pictures were added?

Comment: That aside, what stands out to me here is that in both images, some of the circumferences of triangles are missing. I don't think the algorithm is at fault here, you should probably just double-check your code.

Comment: @peabrainiac thanks for reply. I have randomized the coordinates, so I can't say about the order in the attached images. The data is now overwritten. I have been rechecking the code, but I can't see where the duplicates are coming up.

Comment: Another thing to look at when you check the code is why you have edges that cross. That should not happen in a Delaunay.  Were the crossings there before you removed the super triangle?

Comment: @GaryLucas I will re-check the code. Yes, the crossings to the vertices of super triangle were there. I remove all the triangles having vertices of super triangle in the end. The algorithm doesn't say anything about not considering triangles containing super vertices. I am not sure if that could cause these extra edges.

Comment: @peabrainiac I have updated the question with an example and ordering of coordinates. That might help to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia article about the [Bowyer-Watson-Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowyer%E2%80%93Watson_algorithm) states:

> The Bowyer–Watson algorithm is an incremental algorithm. It works by adding points, one at a time, to a valid Delaunay triangulation of a subset of the desired points. After every insertion, any triangles whose circumcircles contain the new point are deleted, **leaving a star-shaped polygonal hole which is then re-triangulated using the new point**.

In other words, after adding a new point and removing all problematic sides, you need to connect it only to the corners of hole that those removed triangles form, not every point in the graph. That way edges will never intersect, unlike in your three examples.

The article also has a pretty good [pseudo-code implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowyer%E2%80%93Watson_algorithm#Pseudocode) of the algorithm, maybe taking a closer look at that will also help you further.

Comment: Thanks, yes you pointed the issue correctly. I am currently stuck on that part. For example, when 3 points (1 triangle - ignoring super triangle) already exists and 4th point is added on the exterior of triangle (similar to point [1750, 2600] ), how to select the points [1500,1500], [2800,2800] only by ignoring point [3300,1500] ? My current code selects all the edges of Bad Triangle and connects the point to them all.

Comment: [3300,1500] is not the corner of a bad triangle though in that example? so it should get ignored if you on only connect those to [1750,2600]. Maybe you forgot to clear the bad triangles list between adding points or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Using the coordinates you supplied, I get the Delaunay triangulation shown below. Based on my experience with the Bowyer-Watson algorithm, I'd guess that your problem is that you are not removing edges during the "cavity digging" phase of the process (and by "experience" I mean "the mistakes that I've made in the past").  Though, of course, there are plenty of other things that can go wrong.

[image: Delaunay Triangulation]

I've made some notes about my own efforts to implement Bowyer-Watson starting at about page 20 in the document [Tinfour Algorithms and Data Elements](https://gwlucastrig.github.io/TinfourDocs/TinfourAlgorithmsAndDataElements.pdf).  Perhaps they will give you some ideas you can use.

Good luck on your project.  I wish you the best of success.

Gary

Comment: Thank you, @Gary. I will read your document in details, it is highly precise. Thanks for your work on Delaunay.